# Prove that $\gcd(n! + 1, 3n! + 1) = 1$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to prove this by induction but I got stuck, this is what I've got.

Base case: $n = 2$. $\gcd(2! + 1, 3*3!+1) = gcd(3, 7) = 1.$

Inductive step: assuming for $n = k$ that $\gcd(k!+1, 3k!+1) = 1$ holds.
Let $n = k + 1$. We have to prove that $\gcd((k+1)! + 1, 3(k+1)!+1) = 1.$

From assumption we get that:

$\gcd(k!+1, 3k!+1) = 1$

Multiplying this by $k + 1$ we get:

$(k + 1) * \gcd(k!+1, 3k!+1) = k + 1$

Subtracting k from both sides:

$(k + 1) * \gcd(k!+1, 3k!+1) - k = 1$

Now $k+1$ can enter the gcd and we have:

$\gcd((k +1)! + (k + 1), 3(k + 1)! + (k + 1)) - k = 1$

Now I dont know where to proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  gcd$(m+1, 3m+1)=1$ or $2$ ($1$ if $m$ is even, which $n!$ is for $n\ge2)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easier, I think, to do it without induction.

Suppose, to the contrary, that the gcd was greater than $1$.  Then some prime $p$ divides the gcd.  It follows that $p\,|\,((3\times n!+1)-(n!+1))=2\times n!$  Since $n!+1$ is clearly odd, $p$ must be odd as well.  Thus $p\,|\,n!$  But if $p$ divides $n!$ it can not divide $n!+1$, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ The gcd $d$ divides $3(n!\!+\!1)-(3n!\!+\!1) = 2\,$ and $\,d\mid n!\!+\!1 = $ odd $ $ [by $\,2\mid n!\,$ by $\,n\ge 2$]

**Remark** $ $ More generally it's special case $\,a,b,\bar c,c = 3,1,1,n!\,$ in

**Theorem** $\,\ a\!-\!b\mid c,\, (c,\bar c)=1\,\Rightarrow\, d:=(ac\!+\!\bar c,\,bc\!+\!\bar c) = 1$

**Proof** $\ \ d\mid ac\!+\!\bar c\!-\!(bc\!+\!\bar c) = (a\!-\!b)c\mid c^2\,$ so $\,d\mid (c^2,ac\!+\!\bar c)=1\,$ by $(c,ac\!+\!\bar c) = (c,\bar c)= 1$

Answer (score 1):

We have that 
$$\gcd(n! + 1, 3n! + 1) = \gcd(n! + 1, (3n! + 1)-2(n!+1))=$$

$$=\gcd(n! + 1, n! - 1)=\gcd(2, n! - 1)=1$$